# jquery object containing all element definitions

Tags: jquery

Not sure if my title explains what I am trying to do very well, but is it possible to retrieve an object of jquery select definitions including any definitions that were not present in the DOM when the page was loaded so that I can call the object or read it's properties again if required ?

```
    <div id="div1">
    <div id="div3">

    $('#div1').on('click',function(){
        do something...
    })

    $('#div2').on('click',function(){
        do something...
    }).css('background','red').data('xxx','yyy').attr({class:'myclass'})

    $('#div3').on('click',function(){
        do something...
    })

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(jqueryArray['#div2].onClick)
        console.log(jqueryArray['#div2].attr())
        console.log(jqueryArray['#div2].css())
    },2000)
```

In this example, div 1 and 3 existed, but div2 was not present when the page was loaded.

Is there an internal jquery array or object that contains all of the selectors that were parsed during the loading of the page that can be accessed after the page was loaded ?

Comment: In the case of the div2 not existing at the time that runs, your setting of css, data and attr would do nothing.  It does not exist to set upon yet.  Inside your event handler you can see if any of those are set by using the contextualized $(this).css('background'), $(this).data('xxx'), $(this).attr('class')

Answer (score 3):

Your looking for a delegate.

```
$(parentSelector).on(event, childSelector, eventHandler);
```

This functions much like a normal event handler, except it is bound to a parent element that already exists.  Events from the children bubble up and the parent evaluates the child selector to see if they match.  If so it applies the handler against it.

Since it works off of bubbled up events, it does not care when the children were created.  Only that it is getting events.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not just the events that I am looking for it is all the properties and attributes of the element. I have updated the original post with some additional properties.

Comment: Uh, I believe there is $._data(DOM Element, "events") or something that will let you see the events that jquery has registered for an element.  Might be some other keys you can use other than "events", but that's more for debugging.  Not productional code.